# NonlinearModel Fit Help?

Tags: fitting

I'm trying to fit some data to a nonlinear model, but I'm getting the following error:

NonlinearModelFit:: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 1000 iterations.

This is my code right now:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {15, 8960}, {15, 
    15800}, {15, 13900}, {15, 11400}, {30, 6.21}, {30, 11.5}, {30, 
    2.0}, {60, 4.23}, {60, 1.52}, {60, 9.76}, {60, 0}};
model = 
 NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  a*(Exp[k1*t] - Exp[-0.0685625*t]), {a, {k1, -1}, {k2, -1}}, t, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

Is it simply that my data doesn't fit the model well? Or is there something I can change. If I raise the MaxIterations to infinity I just get:

NonlinearModelFit:: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the gradient is larger than the tolerance specified by the AccuracyGoal option. There is a possibility that the method has stalled at a point that is not a local minimum.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: `{30, 6.21}, {30, 11.5}, {30, 
    2.0}` means that it is almost imposible be a function.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. I recommend and request that you stay responsive to the comments so that you can receive further assistance.